# Oracle procedure call fails from jdbc

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

We have a procedure declared in an oracle package with name x_pkg.proc_name. When called from jdbc through java.sql.Statement.execute("BEGIN x_pkg.proc_name; END;"); the call fails with an error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'x_pkg.proc_name' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The above error indicates that the procedure is not declared in the given package. 
The jdbc call surprisingly succeeds if I rename the procedure to x_pkg.proc_name_something. This seems very strange. I tried deleting the procedure declaration and its body and re-adding it but I get the same error.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting this further?

Note - the procedure call succeeds always through pl-sql code. It just fails when executed through jdbc.

**Update :** 
It procedure call succeeds if I prefix it with the schema name like "BEGIN schema_name.x_pkg.proc_name; END;"

Any idea when should the schema name be prefixed and when is it not required?

**Update :**
The actual package name is "COMMONS_UTILS" and the procedure name is "SET_SESSION_NLS_PARAMS". The call "BEGIN COMMONS_UTILS.SET_SESSION_NLS_PARAMS; END;" fails when made through JDBC. It works if I rename the procedure name to "SET_SESSION_NLS_PARAMSX".

**Update :** 
The procedure call works if I compile it before executing it.

"BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PACKAGE COMMONS_UTILS COMPILE'; COMMONS_UTILS.SET_SESSION_NLS_PARAMS; END;"

Comment: can you post the package spec at the minimum? also, you sure that x_pkg doesn't exists in multiple schemas and your java has rights?

Comment: May be the user you are using to connect to with Oracle does not know about the package! Maybe you have to do some thing like `schema.x_pkg.proc_name`.... Maybe the name `proc_name` is a reserved keyword..... Maybe something else!

Comment: Rights could not be an issue since it works if I rename the proc. I also verified that proc_name is not a reserved keyword. How do you verify if the user I am connecting knows about the package or no? Note that renaming the proc works!. I understand that this is a very strange issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the package name actually `x_pkg` and the procedure name `proc_name`? If not, please edit your post and include this information at the end. Thanks.

Comment: Done! I have added the actual package name and procedure name above.